# Type-Safe Linking using DWARF

Tags: gcc, linker, ld, type-safety, dwarf

Why doesn't GCC together with GNU ld support type-checked linking when the DWARF-format contains all the type-information we need? We waste a lot of time on our company trying to make Ada and C communicate safely. The problem is we have no help from the compiler nor linked to assure that these bindings are kept in sync.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why doesn't GCC together with GNU ld support type-checked linking when the DWARF-format contains all the type-information we need?

The problem is significantly more complex than you make it appear.

> We waste a lot of time on our company trying to make Ada and C communicate safely.

Then code support for this into GNU `ld` or `gold` (the latter is much faster, and much easier to hack on), and contribute it upstream. Problem solved?

Comment: Which are the complexities involved?

Comment: According to the following article the problem seems closely related to module systems: http://www.cs.umd.edu/~mwh/papers/cmod-journal.pdf

Comment: BTW: I like your name, Employed Russian:)